# Botones en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una pregunta , necesito completar un formulario en html en el cual al oprimir un boton me agregue un nuevo usuario mediante cedula , pais , continente , numero de celular , tengo el codigo en javascript de las funciones en visual ,  "function agregar(cedula,pais,continente,numero celular)" , estaba agregandolo introduciendo los parametros por consola , pero ahora quiero hacerlo en forma de formulario con campos de texto , y que al darle click al boton me agrege el nuevo usuario , alguna idea de como hacerlo ?

Comment: Que has intentado? Por favor agrega tu código

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Bootstrap Forms e integrar JQuery para que puedas obtener los datos de los inputs.

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/
- https://api.jquery.com/val/

Ejemplo obtener valores de input por jquery

```
<input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre" />
```

-

```
function getNombre() {
   console.log($("#nombre").val());
}
```